# Determine the number of times a null value occurs in column B for a distinct value in column A, SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with "name" as one column, date as another, and location as a third. The location column supports null values.

I am trying to write a query to determine the number of times a null value occurs in the location column for each distinct value in the name column.

Can someone please assist?

Comment: what have you tried so far and any sample date ?

Answer (score 3):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select name, sum(case when location is null then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by name;
```

Another method that involves slightly less typing is:

```
select name, count(*) - count(location)
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

use count along with filters, as you only requires Null occurrence

```
select name, count(*) occurances
from mytable 
where location is null
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you'll want to get a distinct list of all different 'name' rows, and then you would like a count of how many NULLs there are per each name.

The following will achieve this:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as null_counts
FROM table 
WHERE location IS NULL
GROUP BY name
```

The WHERE clause will only retrieve records where the records have NULL as their location.

The GROUP BY will pivot the data based on NAME.

The SELECT will give you the name, and the COUNT(*) of the number of records, per name.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.